# python simhash import issue [github.com/seomoz/simhash-py]

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-16.04, python-module

I've installed simhash using below command

```
pip install git+https://github.com/seomoz/simhash-py.git
```

and to check if it has been installed successfully below is the o/p of `pip  freeze`

```
pip freeze | grep simhash
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
simhash-py==0.4.0
```

While running the below test case, i.e.,

```
import unittest  
import simhash

class TestNumDifferingBits(unittest.TestCase):
    '''Tests about num_differing_bits'''

    def test_basic(self):
        a = 0xDEADBEEF
        b = 0xDEADBEAD
        self.assertEqual(2, simhash.num_differing_bits(a, b))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

which I copied from [here](https://github.com/seomoz/simhash-py/blob/master/test/test.py), I got below errors

```
ImportError: Failed to import test module: simhashGitHubTest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 254, in _find_tests
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 232, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/pallav/PycharmProjects/pfda/src/simhashTest/simhashGitHubTest.py", line 4, in <module>
    import simhash
ImportError: No module named simhash
```

Then, I replaced the name of the package to simhash-py(as pip) due to which I got below errors:

```
    import simhash-py as simhash
                  ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Kindly help me out in running the test cases.

```
pip -V
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

Command for running test case(copied from PyCharm)

```
python -m unittest discover -s /home/pallav/PycharmProjects/pfda/src/simhashTest -p simhashGitHubTest.py -t /home/pallav/PycharmProjects/pfda/src/simhashTest in /home/pallav/PycharmProjects/pfda/src/simhashTest
```

Comment: can you paste the result of `pip -V` in a terminal ?

Comment: @PRMoureu Done, Please check

Comment: ok, and how do you execute the test file ?

Comment: @PRMoureu Done, Please check

Comment: not sure why it cant find the module, maybe a path is missing : could you check `import sys;print '\n'.join(sys.path)`   ? and do you see `simhash` when you input `help('modules')` in a python terminal ?

Comment: @PRMoureu It got resolved, please refer the answer for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've installed it via an another method.

```
git clone https://github.com/seomoz/simhash-py.git
cd simhash-py
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Then changed the value of named parameter 'name' to `simhash` from `simhash-py` which was being passed to `setup` method in `~/setup.py` file and then

```
sudo python setup.py install
```